# How to hide cmd.exe and cscript command prompts?

Tags: windows, cmd, wsh, jscript, windows-console

I have a `test.cmd` file on my desktop. In it contains the following line:

```
cmd.exe /c "cscript foo.js"
```

Is it possible to completely silence/quiet/supress/hide any and all console windows from popping up? I would like to execute the .cmd without any popup windows.

Answer (score 4):

Create on your desktop a shortcut file (*.lnk) with the command line:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\wscript.exe foo.js
```

Then the JScript file is interpreted with GUI version of Windows Script Host instead of the console version which prevents displaying a console window.

Run `wscript /?` for help on this executable in comparison to `cscript /?`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try right click on shortcut -> Properties -> Run -> minimised.  Not perfect but maybe no-one will notice.